# How do I convert a list of values into a list of names for enum?

Tags: python, list, enums, mergesort

Let's say that I have a list and I sort it by using `mergeSort`. How can I convert the sorted list such that I will see the names of the Animals instead of the values?

```
theList = [Animal.Bear.value,Animal.Ant.value,Animal.Lion]

mergeSort(theList)

print(theList)
```

Comment: There is no `mergeSort` function in Python that I'm aware of, and it would have to be in some separate library if there were. There is not enough info here to answer the question, please give a [mcve].

Comment: `Animal.Bear.value` also doesn't exist generally. Almost certainly, you've got quite a bit of your own code behind this and we can see none of it.

Comment: @roganjosh The title, at least, mentions `enum`, which I assume means there was a definition like `class Animal(Enum): Bear = 1 Ant = 2 Lion = 3`.

Comment: If you were using `sort`, I would suggest not storing a list of values in the first place. `theList = [Animal.Bear, Animal.Ant, Animal.Lion]; theList.sort(key=lambda x: x.value)`.

Comment: @chepner good point. I'm not sure whether that renders my comment moot because (although probably correct) we're not given a clear picture here

Answer (score 1):

You could go over the list and convert the values to names by going through the enum constructor:

```
nameList = [Animal(x).name for x in theList];
```

Comment: Thanks. I found another way :)